# Inappropriate value - string expected - when used with count+ index

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-template-file

I am stuck with the below problem (terraform v0.12.8);

Where i am trying to use below as my module code and passing them to below resource;

```
module "nat_gateway" {
    source           = "../providers/aws/network/nat_gw/"
    total_nat_gws    = "${length(var.availability_zones)}"
    eip_id           = "${module.eip.*.eip_id}"
    target_subnet_id = "${module.public_subnet.*.subnet_id}"
    nat_gw_name_tag  = "NAT-${var.stack_name}"
}
```

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
    count         = "${var.total_nat_gws}"
    allocation_id = "${element("${var.eip_id}", count.index)}"
    subnet_id     = "${element("${var.target_subnet_id}", count.index)}"

    tags = {
        Name = "${var.nat_gw_name_tag}"
    }
}
```

I expected, it would create multiple NAT gateways with the provided multiple EIP's and subnet's. But fails with below error;

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../providers/aws/network/nat_gw/nat_gateway.tf line 12, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw":
  12:     allocation_id = "${element("${var.eip_id}", count.index)}"

Inappropriate value for attribute "allocation_id": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../providers/aws/network/nat_gw/nat_gateway.tf line 12, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw":
  12:     allocation_id = "${element("${var.eip_id}", count.index)}"

Inappropriate value for attribute "allocation_id": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../providers/aws/network/nat_gw/nat_gateway.tf line 13, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw":
  13:     subnet_id     = "${element("${var.target_subnet_id}", count.index)}"

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../providers/aws/network/nat_gw/nat_gateway.tf line 13, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw":
  13:     subnet_id     = "${element("${var.target_subnet_id}", count.index)}"
```

Can someone please help correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly interpolating things there with your nested braces.

Instead this should look like the following:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  count         = "${var.total_nat_gws}"
  allocation_id = "${element(var.eip_id, count.index)}"
  subnet_id     = "${element(var.target_subnet_id, count.index)}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.nat_gw_name_tag}"
  }
}
```

As you aren't relying on the behaviour of `element` that allows looping back through list by selecting indexes that are longer than the length you can simplify this to:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  count         = "${var.total_nat_gws}"
  allocation_id = "${var.eip_id[count.index]}"
  subnet_id     = "${var.target_subnet_id[count.index]}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.nat_gw_name_tag}"
  }
}
```

Because you're using Terraform 0.12 you could also directly use the variables instead of using the interpolation syntax to go even further with:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  count         = var.total_nat_gws
  allocation_id = var.eip_id[count.index]
  subnet_id     = var.target_subnet_id[count.index]

  tags = {
    Name = var.nat_gw_name_tag
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @ydaetskcoR for the help and suggestions related to v12.0. I have corrected accordingly. But it shows me a new error now;
`
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../providers/aws/network/nat_gw/nat_gateway.tf line 12, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw":
  12:     allocation_id = var.eip_id[count.index]

Inappropriate value for attribute "allocation_id": string required.
`

Comment: Thanks, @ydaetskcoR, the above error has been issue fixed with solution from https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22350#issuecomment-519163316